# Redirect_to not sending object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As part of a logging in, I redirect back to the original controller and action if the `User` doesn't save. But the original controller isn't receiving the `resource` object.

In `registrations_controller.rb`

```
redirect_to m_signup_after_job_post_path(resource, job: params[:job_id])
```

In `pages_controller.rb`

```
def signup_after_job_post
  resource ||= User.new
  respond_with(resource)
end
```

Comment: I don't understand how the code you posted is supposed to interact. Where is `resource` getting set? The local variable `resource` won't magically get passed with the redirect.

Comment: Totally agree... so I guess I'm looking to simply pass the object from one controller action to another?

Answer (score 1):

Although the helpers like `something_path` take the object itself, internally they just call the `.id` method of that object and pass only the ID into the route itself.  So in the action that receives that route you will always need to do something like:

```
resource = User.find params[:id]
```

Comment: I had no idea. Thanks

Comment: Ok, the issue is that the resource doesn't have an ID yet. It hasn't yet been saved to the database.

Comment: Then you probably shouldn't be redirecting, usually in those cases you just render the view that sent the object (which will display the errors that prevented the object from being created). Just gleaning what I can from the names of your methods/helper, you're allowing someone to post a job without creating a user first? You should probably rethink that, even if you just create a (mostly) empty user that they're going to fill in later, you will want a valid `user_id` in your job record.

Comment: Regarding job without user: You're correct - you can post a job without a user. We just assign the user afterwards. It's atypical in terms of database structure - creating a child before the parent - but it makes sense in terms of the onboarding flow. Creating a shell user would be difficult in this case, as I'm using devise which has validation that prevents user creation without the right info - it requires a password and so on.

Comment: `.save validate: false`

Comment: Regarding render: That makes sense. I found it had some odd bugs as it was rendering the layout in a different environment, but if that's the only way, I'll give it another try! Thanks.

Comment: Interesting - what about the possibility of bad data in the User database?

Comment: Well, you're already (I assume) dealing with the same issue in your jobs table which will have an empty `user_id` unless they complete their signup. I think that even having just the `created_at` date for a User (although there's more that you can store, such as the IP address that they were using at the time) is better than having no User record at all and a Job post with an empty `user_id`